# How to insert/copy in Excel base on number of another column in Excel VBA or not

Tags: excel, vba

Basically, I would like a simple way to the following example scenario :
Number of times of A,B and C copied based on lines of numbers.
Number of lines are much more than below example in real cases of course.

From

```
A  1
B  2
C  3
   6
   7
```

to

```
A  1
A  2
A  3
A  6
A  7
B  1
B  2
B  3
B  6
B  7
C  1
C  2
C  3
C  6
C  7
```

Any quick way?

To follow up,

Below function and VBA solved my question above.

Used below function to get the first column

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,ROUNDUP(ROW()/5,0))
```

Anyone know a corresponding VBA code for this part? The function works, however, it is not very convenient when there are too many lines. It will be great to set range in VBA.

The second column used VBA code as below (Tried multiple columns so be VBA is slightly different with the question) :

```vb
Sub Macro1()
    '
    ' Macro1 Macro
    '
    Dim lastRow As Long

    ' Subdivision total row number
    a = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Porject total row number
    b = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ' Project total cell range
    Range("B1:C5").Copy
    Range("F1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Paste
    ' Row number need to -1 as the first copy is done above
    For i = 1 To A - 1
        lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Range("F" & lastRow).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Quickest way would be to include the code that you already have into your question and tell where you got stuck or errors. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

Below function and VBA solved my question above.

Used below function to get the first column

=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,ROUNDUP(ROW()/5,0))

Anyone know a corresponding VBA code for this part? The function works, however, it is not very convenient when there are too many lines. IT will be great to set range in VBA.

The second column used VBA code as below (Tried multiple columns so be VBA is slightly different with the question) :

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
 Dim lastRow As Long

 ' Subdivision total row number
    a = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  ' Porject total row number
    b = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    ' Project total cell range
    Range("B1:C5").Copy
    Range("F1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet1").Paste
    ' Row number need to -1 as the first copy is done above
  For i = 1 To A - 1
    lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range("F" & lastRow).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to ask a question, please put everything into the question part. You cannot ask questions in the answer part, because we cannot answer follow-up questions here. I suggest you copy everything into your original question and delete this answer here.